# How to set weight in Weighted Kernel K-Means?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, k-means, clustering

The objective function of kernel K-means is

$$      \sum\limits_{c=1}^k \sum\nolimits_{a_i \in c}   w_i \Vert \phi(a_i)- m_c \Vert^2 \ $$

where

$$ m_c = \frac{\sum\nolimits_{a_i \in c }w_i\phi(a_i)}{\sum\nolimits_{a_i \in c  }w_i}  $$
I need to know how to determine wi

Comment: If possible, it would be better if you can rewrite the Obj. func. in Latex :)  [I don't know Latex, so couldn't make the edit]

Answer (score 1):

These weights should be introduced by a user. With a weight you tell the K-means algorithm, that one feature is more important than the other.

> [0] These might represent a measure of importance, a frequency count, or some other information. The intent is that a point with a weight of 5.0 is twice as "important" as a point with a weight of 2.5, for instance. This gives rise to the "weighted" K-Means problem.

[0] http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/kmeans/kmeans.html